# What do &OPTIONAL and &REST mean in a VALUES type specifier?

Tags: common-lisp

CLHS states "The &optional and &rest markers can appear in the value-type list; they indicate the parameter list of a function that, when given to multiple-value-call along with the values, would correctly receive those values."  Can someone please explain what this means?

CLHS states elsewhere that the VALUES type specifier "can be used only as the value-type in a function type specifier or a the special form".  This being the case, I don't understand how CLHS can talk about how a VALUES type specifier can "indicate the parameter list of a function".  It seems to be a contradiction, not to mention an inscrutable saying.  How can the type declaration of a function's value-type (return type) say something about the function's (or some other function's--it's not really clear) formal parameters?

**EDIT:**

I asked this question on the sbcl-help list, and one of the devs responded "&optional appears, therefore the VALUES list is treated as the full argument-like syntax. It corresponds to a function with type (FUNCTION (SYMBOL &OPTIONAL) *), i.e. a function of exactly one argument that must be of type SYMBOL."

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I understand this passage. At least it makes sense to me, so I may claim understanding it :)

I think that what it is trying to say is that the `(values ...)` form must be compatible with the arguments lambda list of the function, which, if called from `multiple-value-call` would have received these arguments correctly.

In other words, suppose there are two functions: `f` and `g`. `f` returns values: `(integer &rest more-integers)` - in human language: it can return one ore more integers. Then, if you want to call `(multiple-value-call #'g (f))` you must (you is a compiler, actually) make sure that the signature of `g` is `(ftype (function (integer &rest more-integers) t))`. The return type of `g` doesn't matter.

Here's my attempt at making an example illustrating it:

```
CL-USER> (declaim (ftype (function () (values integer &rest more-integers)) f))
; No value
CL-USER> (defun f () (values 1 2))
F
CL-USER> (declaim (ftype (function (integer &rest more-integers) t) g))
; No value
CL-USER> (defun g (x &rest rest) (reduce #'+ rest :initial-value x))
G
CL-USER> (multiple-value-call #'g (f))
3
CL-USER> (declaim (ftype (function (single-float) t) x))
; No value
CL-USER> (defun x (y) y)
X
CL-USER> (multiple-value-call #'g (x 1.5))
; Evaluation aborted on #<TYPE-ERROR expected-type: INTEGER datum: 1.5>.
```

Comment: Your answer seems identical to the one given by the SBCL dev in the original question. However, I like yours better because in addition to describing what &OPTIONAL and &REST mean in this context, it actually makes sense of what the spec tries to say.

Comment: However, your example is not apropos.  In the last line, the error is in the type passed to X, not in the type returned by it.  Try this:

    (declaim (ftype (function (integer number) t) g))
    (defun g (x y) (+ x y))
    (declaim (ftype (function () (values integer &optional)) x))
    (defun x () 230)
    (multiple-value-call #'g (x))
    ; Evaluation aborted on #<SB-INT:SIMPLE-PROGRAM-ERROR "invalid number of arguments: ~S" {100408A463}>.

Comment: NOTE: The type correspondence between the function's value-type (return type) and another's parameter list is only checked if &OPTIONAL or &REST are present in the VALUES type specifier for the former's value-type declaration.

Comment: @nbtrap I think that the specifics of how types are checked is up to the compiler implementation. This could be probably one of those caveats where the standard is prescriptive about one side of the things, but doesn't tell anything about the rest (i.e. number / structure of arguments being more important then their types). I understood this error as being the result of compiler inferring the type that must have been passed to `x` based on how it is called. But other compilers may not do this (or at all) type inference.

Comment: That's the point I was trying to make. If you look at the CLHS entry for VALUES (the type specifier), it prescribes the value-type-to-parameter-type(s) correspondence when &OPTIONAL or &REST is present in the value-type specifier, but doesn't prescribe it when they're not.

And you're right about the compiler complaining about the type passed to X. My point is that that's not what you were trying to demonstrate. I understood you to be demonstrating a type mismatch between X's return type and G's parameter type.